# DB2 update column with incrementing number based on distinct values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-update, db2

For each distinct `ref_no` value, I want to update the `seq_no` column with a running sequence of incrementing values starting from 1.

```
REF_NO  SEQ_NO (initial)    SEQ_NO (expected)
------- -------             -------
   111.      -                   1.
   111.      -                   2.
   111.      -                   3.
   222.      -                   1.
   222.      -                   2.
   333.      -                   1.
   100.      -                   1.
   100.      -                   2.
   100.      -                   3.
   100.      -                   4.
     0.      -                   1.
   333.      -                   2.
   100.      -                   5.
   200.      -                   1.
```

I have only been able to do this using a repetition of multiple statements:

```
declare x1 cursor for select * from xyz where seq_no is null for update of seq_no
open x1

fetch from x1
update xyz a set a.seq_no = (select nvl(max(b.seq_no)+1, 1) from xyz b where b.ref_no = a.ref_no) where current of x1
  -- REPEAT ABOVE TWO STATEMENTS UNTIL FETCH RETURNS NO ROW --

close x1
select * from xyz
```

Is it possible to do this entirely using a single `UPDATE` statement run only once to update the entire table? The database is IBM DB2.

Note: The actual order of the rows of a distinct ref_no is arbitrary and does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Row_Number` window function

```
select row_number()over(partition by REF_NO  order by REF_NO) as seq_no
from yourtable
```

To update the table try this

```
MERGE INTO xyz A
USING (SELECT rowid row_id,
              Row_number()
                OVER(
                  partition BY ref_no
                  ORDER BY ref_no ) as seq_no
       FROM   xyz) B
ON A.rowid = B.row_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET A.seq_no = B.seq_no
```

Comment: Ok this shows the values as I expected, but how would I update the `seq_no` column with them? I need to have them stored.

Comment: @ADTC the rows are identical? or is there some value different between them so we can identify them

Comment: There are no other columns, so the rows are indeed identical. However, there's a *system column* called `rowid` that appears to differentiate each row. I tried to use this to do update, but the statement is failing: `update xyz A set A.seq_no = (select B.seq_no from (select rowid row_id, row_number() over(partition by ref_no order by ref_no) as seq_no from xyz) B where A.rowid = B.row_id)`

Comment: @ADTC - note that `rowid` isn't stable in the face of reorgs and a few other things.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I think it's OK if you are just temporarily using it during the `MERGE` statement execution, not storing it anywhere for later recall. And as long as I am sure the DB is not doing any reorg or other things during the execution. Right?

Comment: @ADTC - Yeah, pretty much.  Your statement is already unstable, given `ref_no` isn't unique, so a little extra "over time" won't make much difference.  It was just more a general caution not to rely on it in place of `seq_no`....

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I don't understand what you mean by *"Your statement is already unstable"* and *"a little extra"*. The semantics of `ref_no` and `seq_no` are for me to define however I want to. `ref_no` isn't unique because I don't need it to be unique. My goal is to populate the seq_no based on the non-unique ref_no.

Comment: Besides, your comment was about the stability of `rowid` pseudo-column, which has nothing to do with the actual columns of the table. If `rowid` remains unique **and** unchanged during statement execution, isn't that enough? I'm not storing the `rowid`, so it wouldn't matter if the `rowid` of a row changed after statement has already finished executing. When it executes a second time, it would use the new `rowid`.

Comment: @ADTC - Sorry. What I was referring to was that, because `ref_no` is non-unique, resetting (removing) the `seq_no` values and re-populating them isn't guaranteed to get you the same results.  The `rowid` just adds a bit if you try to do something like order by "most recent added", because it's not assigned that way.  For what you're doing, you're safe - just, it's better to have deliberately-stored unique keys.  I'm not certain you can actually update a table while a re-org is happening anyways...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have table primary key you could use [Relative Record Number SQL Function](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscarrn.htm) and the query below to update your results:

```
MERGE INTO
    ref AS r
USING
    (
        SELECT
            RRN(ref) AS rrn,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ref_no ORDER BY RRN(ref)) AS seq_no
        FROM
            ref
    ) AS n
ON
    RRN(r) = n.rrn
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        seq_no = n.seq_no;
```

Generally it is a bad idea to not have a primary key column on your table. Consider adding identity column. It could be done at already existed table:

```
ALTER TABLE ref ADD COLUMN id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE ref ALTER COLUMN id SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
```